# Python: using 'or' in an if statement causes code to execute even if conditions were not met

Tags: python, if-statement

I am in the process of writing a parser in which two lines are compared together (the 'mainline' so to speak and the line that came before it). If both of those lines match, the mainline is discarded. I only want this to happen on lines that consist only of newlines or carriage returned newlines. So I have this code

```
lastline = 0
pointer = 0
for lines in fileLines:
    mainline = fileLines[pointer]
    if lastline != 0:
        print "Last Line: ",lastline
        print "This Line: ",mainline
        if lastline == '\n' or '\r\n':
            if mainline == '\n' or '\r\n':
                print "Would drop"
    lastline = mainline
    pointer = pointer + 1
```

Every single time it goes through that for loop it will print "Would drop", when the string is certainly not any of those four options. I figure I'm doing something completely backwards, but I'm teaching python to myself so I don't really have anyone to tell me when I'm going about something wrong. Thank god you guys are here. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks to all of your help it is working perfect. Thanks!!!

Comment: The answers below have addressed the errors in your code.  But it's important to note that you do not have to code explicitly for different line endings.  See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lastline == '\n' or '\r\n'
```

is the same as

```
(lastline == '\n') or ('\r\n')
(lastline == '\n') or bool('\r\n')
(lastline == '\n') or True 
True
```

You want either

```
if lastline in ('\n', '\r\n'):
```

or

```
if lastline == '\n' or lastline == '\r\n':
```

Comment: Can't edit, but don't you mean `if lastline == '\n' or...` instead of `if lastline in == '\n'` on that last example?

Answer (score 4):

You actually need:

```
if mainline == '\n' or mainline == '\r\n'
```

Without that change, your code is currently asking asking:

```
is mainline == '\n' True?
or
is '\r\n' True?
```

And since non-blank strings evaluate to `True`, the answer to the second question is always yes.

Answer (score 3):

`lastline == '\n' or '\r\n'` is the same as `(lastline == '\n') or '\r\n'` (which is always true), *not* `lastline == '\n' or lastline == '\r\n'`.

You want `lastline in ('\n', '\r\n')` instead (similarly for the second one).

Answer (score 1):

you are using the `or` wrong.
you should write

```
if lastline == '\n' or lastline == 'r\n':
 ....
```

otherwise the if is always true.

Answer (score 1):

**note:**  See the other answers to address the errors in your code.  This answer is about newlines.

Python has [universal newline support](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) so that you don't have to worry about line endings:

```
fnames = ['a.txt','b.txt']
endings = ['\n', '\r\n']
for fname, ending in zip(fnames, endings):
    with open(fname, 'wb') as f_out: # explicitly 'wb' for binary
        f_out.write('a%sb%s' % (ending, ending))


for mode in ('rb', 'r'):
    print 'mode:', mode
    for fname in fnames:
        with open(fname, mode) as f_in:
            print "%s contains :  %s" % (fname, repr(f_in.read()))
    print
```

gives

```
mode: rb
a.txt contains :  'a\nb\n'
b.txt contains :  'a\r\nb\r\n'

mode: r
a.txt contains :  'a\nb\n'
b.txt contains :  'a\nb\n'
```

The lesson here is that if you don't open your files in binary mode, you need not worry about line endings.